# cygwin cp cannot stat file

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am trying to run the below script and copy the files with particular pattern of names from Source to working.

```
#!/bin/bash
(set -o igncr) 2>/dev/null && set -o igncr; # this comment is required
SOURCE="D:/backup/"
WORKING="D:/copyFromHere/"
Copy_Pattern="P0689\|P1391\|P0730"

for FILE in $(find "$SOURCE" `ls -Rl "$SOURCE" | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'` -print 
2>/dev/null | grep "$COPY_PATTERN" |sed 's/_[0-9]\+//' | uniq);

do
cp -f "FILE" "$WORKING";

done;
```

i am running it on cygwin on windows.

But i am getting below error
cp cannot stat file no such file or directory

Please help me figuring this out.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I make a slight recommendation:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xv
(set -o igncr) 2>/dev/null && set -o igncr; # this comment is required
SOURCE="D:/backup/"
WORKING="D:/copyFromHere/"
Copy_Pattern="P0689\|P1391\|P0730"

for FILE in $(find "$SOURCE" `ls -Rl "$SOURCE" | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'` -print 2>/dev/null | grep "$COPY_PATTERN" |sed 's/_[0-9]\+//' | uniq);
do
    echo "cp -f \"FILE\" \"$WORKING\"";
done;
set +xv
```

The `set -xv` is a debugger for shell. It prints out the line being executed as written in your shell script, and then prints out the line after all variable interpolations have been made. This will let you see each set your program is taking, and where it might be having problems. The `set +xv` just turns off the debugging.

I suspect that the problem is in `cp -f "FILE" "$WORKING"` line because the file `FILE` doesn't actually exist. I also suspect you're picking up file names (and copying fails there), and you may not be checking if directories actually exist before you copy files there. Use the `set -o xv` and you'll see a lot of these errors quite clearly.

Putting your `cp` in an `echo` statement will also let you see what you're planning on executing before actually executing it. It's another way to help debug shell scripts.

I also suspect your `for` loop might not be doing exactly what you want. It's an overly complex bad boy where you're executing two sub-shell commands at once. (Once using `$(..)` and another using back-ticks. I am vehemently against the use of `for var in $(find ...)` because of all sorts of issues. First, the `find` has to finish executing before the `for` loop can begin -- there's no parallel operation. Second, if there are funky file names, your `for` will simply fail. Third, it's very possible that `find` returns so many files, that your command buffer overflows and silently drops names of files without even letting you know it is happening. You're way better using:

```
 find ... | while read something
```

It eliminates many of the issues that your `for` will run into.

Answer (score 1):

`"FILE"` is just a string. you're trying to copy a file whose name is literally `FILE`. perhaps you meant

```
cp -f "$FILE" "$WORKING";
       ^--- missing $?
```

Comment: I did FILE in $(find "$SOURCE" `ls -Rl "$SOURCE" | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'` -print 2>/dev/null | grep "$COPY_PATTERN" |sed 's/_[0-9]\+//' | uniq); in the above step

Comment: yes, you used file in the for loop, but to actually **USE** the $FILE variable, you have to use it as `$FILE`. `"FILE"` by itself is just a string that contains an `F`, an `I`, an `L`,  and an `E`, not the filename that was assigned to $FILE in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable names are case sensitive in Cygwin (as in all POSIX shells, and unlike Windows), so `$Copy_Pattern` (set to `P0689|P1391|P0730`) and `$COPY_PATTERN` (not defined) are two different variables.

You should also be aware of the `-x` command-line switch to bash, which will run your script in trace mode. This is very helpful in debugging a bash script, and I'm sure it would help you find what the problem is here.